# How to solve this pull request problem on bitbucket? We can't let you see this page To access this page

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

I cloned the repo, made some changes, tested them, created a new local branch, commited my changes.  So I try to push to origin but I am apparently forbidden from doing that (403). I solved in some ways. setting a different URL. and now, If I click on the 'create pull request' button (on the company test page bitBucket)it just says 'we can't let you see this page'. To access this page, you may need to log in with another account. You can also return to the previous page or go back to your dashboard.

I never used BitBucket

Comment: You're logged in as 'user' or another user without admin privileges?

Answer (score 0):

- Login as admin (default: admin, admin)
- Navigate to the project that holds the relevant branch
- Click on 'Settings' (gear on the left)
- Click on 'Project permissions'
- Write your username in the 'Add Users' field and change 'Read' into 'Write' in the drop down menu
- click on 'Add'